# Pandas plot hide some x-axis labels

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a dictionary where the keys are dates and the values are integers. I want to fill missing dates with zeroes and plot it. Here's what I've got so far.

```
data = {datetime.date(2018, 1, 26): 1, datetime.date(2018, 1, 18): 1, datetime.date(2018, 1, 11): 4, datetime.date(2017, 12, 31): 2, datetime.date(2018, 1, 14): 1, datetime.date(2018, 1, 9): 2, datetime.date(2018, 1, 7): 1, datetime.date(2018, 1, 16): 2, datetime.date(2018, 1, 15): 2, datetime.date(2018, 1, 10): 1, datetime.date(2018, 1, 5): 1, datetime.date(2018, 1, 13): 3} 
dates = pd.date_range('2018-01-01', date.today())
data = pd.Series(data=data)
data = data.reindex(dates, fill_value=0) 
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15, 7))
data.plot(kind='bar', ax=ax)
plt.xticks(rotation=45)
plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_formatter(plt.FixedFormatter(data.index.to_series().dt.strftime("%b %d")))
```

The problem I'm running into is that now the x-axis is crammed with too many date labels. How can I still show all the points on the graph, but only label half the ticks on the x-axis?

EDIT: Potential Solution:

I was able to skip every 2nd x-axis label by adding this code:

```
xticks = ax.xaxis.get_major_ticks()
for i in range(0, len(xticks)):
    if i % 2 != 0:
        xticks[i].label1.set_visible(False)
```

Comment: Please, add data for `data` so your example can be reproducible.

Comment: Added actual data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `pd.plot` when you need to customize axis it's a little complicated. In the end, `pandas` calls `matplotlib`, so you can do:

```
from datetime import date
from matplotlib import  dates


data = {datetime.date(2018, 1, 26): 1, 
        datetime.date(2018, 1, 18): 1, 
        datetime.date(2018, 1, 11): 4, 
        datetime.date(2017, 12, 31): 2, 
        datetime.date(2018, 1, 14): 1, 
        datetime.date(2018, 1, 9): 2, 
        datetime.date(2018, 1, 7): 1, 
        datetime.date(2018, 1, 16): 2, 
        datetime.date(2018, 1, 15): 2, 
        datetime.date(2018, 1, 10): 1, 
        datetime.date(2018, 1, 5): 1, 
        datetime.date(2018, 1, 13): 3} 

dates_ = pd.date_range('2018-01-01', date.today()).to_pydatetime()
data = pd.Series(data=data)
data = data.reindex(dates_, fill_value=0) 
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15, 7))

ax.bar(data.index, data.values)

ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(dates.DayLocator(bymonthday=range(1,32),interval=2))
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(dates.DateFormatter('%b\n\n%d'))
ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(dates.DayLocator(bymonthday=range(1,32),
                                            interval=1))

plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think `Series.fillna()` would do that: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.fillna.html

Your script would be thus:

```
data = <my dictionary>    
dates = pd.date_range('2018-01-01', date.today())
data = pd.Series(data=data)
data = data.fillna(0, inplace=True)
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15, 7))
data.plot(kind='bar', ax=ax)
plt.xticks(rotation=45)
plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_formatter(plt.FixedFormatter(data.index.to_series().dt.strftime("%b %d")))
```